# Django - How to combine Authen middleware and my custom middleware?

Tags: python, django

I have an api that require `Token` in headers and users must have role `is_staff` to process.

Here is my `model.py` to clarify about `is_staff` role

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Custom user model that support using email instead of username"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Here is the api in my `views.py`

```
class get_user_info_from_token(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    def get(self, request):        

        """ I put the below rows in middleware
       
        User = Token.objects.get(key = request.auth).user
        if User.is_staff: 
        """

        return HttpResponse("You are staff)
```

Here is my middleware:

```
class CustomMiddlware(object):
    ...
    def __call__(self, request):
        token = request.headers['Authorization'][6:]

        user = Token.objects.get(key=token).user
        if user.is_staff:
            response = self.get_response(request)
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden("You are not allowed")
    ...
```

Well I have 2 questions:

1/ I want to put `permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )` into my middlware to simplyfy my code. But I do not  know how to do it.

2/ Moreover, in my middleware, I can not run `User = Token.objects.get(key = request.auth).user` since I got this error `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'auth'`.

Comment: DRF's authentication classes are responsible for assigning `auth` and `user` attributes into the `request` object (if you are using DRF APIs). These actions are taking place after the execution of *all middlewares*. Hence, you won't be able to identify the requested user in your middleware in the case of DRF

Comment: You can do this in a custom authentication class instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends which one you are familiar with. Provided you are new. Then consider picking 1.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30371922)